# How do identify drift at record level in cosmos db?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am new to cosmos db and trying to understand the concept of change feed. I understand that change feeds helps by tracking inserts/updates on container records. Can someone help me with the scenario where I would like to keep historical data on each record ?

I would like to know if any updates are done to a record in cosmos db, how can I keep a copy of old record ? If mutiple updates are done on same record then is it better to keep only part of record that changed or entire record ?

A code sample is appreciated but not required. A conceptual explanation can help as well.

Comment: I think the approach described here is quite a good match with your requirements: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/document-versioning-pattern-azure-cosmos-db-michele-arpaia

Answer (score 1):

This is the document versioning pattern. Here is a simple conceptual design.

This is an append-only store with two containers, one that receives all the inserts or updates. It contains only the most recent version of a document. The second container has all versions of a document. When a document is inserted or updated into the first container, change feed picks that up and copies it into the second container with a new /id value.

Include a document-version property to your data models. This will be value of 1 for every insert and incremented on every update.

One thing to point out here is the id value for each document needs to be unique within a partition key value. To illustrate, if I had an orders container with a partition key of orderId, each version of that order will have a different id value with same partition key (orderId). This is helpful so you can do an efficient, in-partition query for all versions of a document. If the partition key value and id are the same across versions, you will get exceptions when change feed inserts data into the second container.

There is actually some sample content coming that will illustrate this with a sample app. Won't be published for 3-4 weeks however. Hopefully what I've described above gets you there. It's not difficult to implement.